# TFS Workspace confusion

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I installed TFS on my laptop with Sql express. SO i dont have server environment.

I selected local at the time of TFS workspace creation.

Worksapce location is D:\TFSWorkspace

My VS project location: D:\VS 2013 Projects\TestApplicationForTFS

[image: Directories Flow]

There are physical files in my project, but there is nothing in TFSWorkspace Except a folder with project name but its empty.

Is it normal?

TFS workspace dont get the files from developer's project location?

Is it because i selected local and not server?

Comment: What version of VS/TFS are you using? You should be able to change your workspace settings by going File > Source Control > Advanced > Workspaces and do a clean up of the working folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have mapped your project `TestApplicationForTFS` from `D:\VS 2013 Projects\TestApplicationForTFS` to TFS, so the workspace for your project `TestApplicationForTFS` is `D:\VS 2013 Projects\TestApplicationForTFS`.

To change the workspace for project `TestApplicationForTFS`, go to File--Source Control--Advanced--Workspaces, select the workspace you are using, and click Edit, to change the local folder for project `TestApplicationForTFS` to `D:\TFSWorkspace\TFSTestProject\TestApplicationForTFS`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked. A few quick questions if you can answer:
1. $/ this mean root?  2. if there are 5 developers working on same project, and on server machine we install tfs, and connect 5 developers to project on TFS, then project files will be on server machine's workspace? or local workspace(developers).

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It depends you use a local or a server workspace. If you use a local workspace, developers will open the files on their own machine. You can check the difference between local and server workspace: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace